# Bower update returns 'invalid-meta the "name" is recommended to be lowercase' while working with default App name in laravel project

Tags: laravel, bower

I am using 'App'(default) as application name in Laravel project and bower update returns 'invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes.'

Code in bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "App",
    "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "~3.3.6"
    }
}
```

It seems 'App' needs to be replaced by all lowercase in bower.json. Won't this create a namespace issue?

Answer (score 1):

No, Bower is not related to your PHP code at all. You can change the name to whatever you want without it affecting any of your backend code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @ntzm.